# Getting crash on String to date conversion

Tags: objective-c

@"2019-12-27T06:42:35Z"  app crash when stringDate convert into date

```
NSDateFormatter*dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];

NSDate*date = [dateFormat dateFromString:sentDate];
    return  date;
```

Comment: what is the crash? what is the input? too vague question please update.

Comment: input string is @"2019-12-27 06:22:04 +0000"

Comment: @Dileepkumar Your input string is not same with the one you posted in your comment. So which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

The date format you are providing to your date formatter is wrong. So as per your input, your date format should be **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ**